# jquery - How can I create an array from element values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I need to create an array to associate the values from two groups of elements. So when I call the first I get the value of the associated one. Here's what I've tried but it is not working. Can you point me to the right direction?

```
var key1 = jQuery('#edit-line-item-fields-field-select-zone-und option[value="1"]').text();
var price = {
key1 : jQuery('.field-name-field-price-1-zona .field-item').text()
};
console.log(price.key1);
```

Comment: See creating a [mcve]. Would go a long way to showing us a working snippet that may not do what you're trying to do, with some expected results.

Comment: For dynamic key, use bracket notation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use bracket notation:

```
const key = "whatever", value = "value";
const price = {
  [key]: value
};
console.log(price[key]);
```

`price.key` accesses the `key` property of `price`. `price[key]` accesses the property the string in `key` identifies.